# ASP.NET WebApi - SharePoint Claims Authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013, claims-based-identity

I need to migrate some existing WCF services to a new WebAPI-based architecture. Unfortunately, they run on **two SharePoint 2013 farms**, trusted to one another, and rely on **claims authentication** to perform task with the application pool account.

I already have running Web API controllers in SharePoint, but I couldn't find a way to automatically authenticate the system user across farm.

Which is the preferred approach I could rely on?